# How to create a DataFrame with MultiIndex from custom numpy dtype?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am reading a binary file with `np.fromfile` and I want to convert it into a `DataFrame`. The format of the binary file is like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dtyp = np.dtype([
    ('group1', [('item1', 'int'), ('item2', 'int')]),
    ('group2', [('item1', 'int'), ('item2', 'int')])
    ])

arr = np.zeros(shape=2, dtype=dtyp)
```

Now, I want to turn this into a DataFrame, so I tried this:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_records(arr)

   group1  group2
0  (0, 0)  (0, 0)
1  (0, 0)  (0, 0)
```

... but this isn't what I want. The column names `'item1'` and `'item2'` are lost. My desired output has a `MultiIndex` on the columns, like this:

```
  group1       group2      
   item1 item2  item1 item2
0      0     0      0     0
1      0     0      0     0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is not implemented for nested structured arrays. In your case you can
destruct the dtype like that :

```
def mkd(arr):
    d={}
    for n1 in arr.dtype.names:
        for n2 in arr[n1].dtype.names:
                d[(n1,n2)]=arr[n1][n2]
    return pd.DataFrame(d)
```

For

```
In [1]:   mkd(arr)
Out[1]: 
  group1       group2      
   item1 item2  item1 item2
0      0     0      0     0
1      0     0      0     0
2      0     0      0     0
```